# How to get revisions name and edits count using Google Drive API

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am using Google Drive API V3.
I would like to get named versions and edits count using Drive API V3.

[Please check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBxML.png)

I can able to get revisions list but it doesn't have "name" value.
And also It doesn't contain edits count.

I tried following code (.Net)

```
string fileId = "*************";//sorry file id hided
var rev = _service.Revisions.List(fileId);
rev.Fields = "*";
var revs = rev.Execute();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unfortunately this is currently not possible

There is a respective [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/115421149) filed on Google's Issue Tracker.

I recommend you to "star" it to increase visibility and hopefully accelerate implementation.

Comment: okay, Thank you, will update here if any updates